# SNR BER graph ploting alike matlab with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to indicate on graph y-axis logarithmic grids like [SNR plot](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rosa_Alsina-Pages/publication/265168457/figure/download/fig1/AS:614018897170469@1523404921836/Real-and-simulated-measures-of-BER-vs-SNR-for-PSK-and-QPSK.png?_sg=NGrerhfDXWQ24kVoLqIc1DiG5S8sq6sLIOMC461VuW5FoQnVa1YETRStP5IbiAu-ngocXBTmn8k) that enabled dash or dot y-tics. Matlab and similar programs does this, but need to use Gnuplot.

```
### sum up for certain conditions
reset session
set key right box
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"#ffffff" behind
set datafile separator comma
set grid
set output 'logscaled.png'
set logscale y 10
set ytics
show ytics
set y2tics
show ytics

set xlabel "SNR"
set ylabel "BER"

plot "snr-ber.csv" title 'Random' w l


### end of code
```

[image]

| SNR | BER |
| --- | --- |
| -5.00 | 2.8301e-01 |
| -4.00 | 2.6931e-01 |
| -3.00 | 2.3582e-01 |
| -2.00 | 2.2382e-01 |
| -1.00 | 1.511e-01 |
| 0.00 | 1.4879e-01 |
| 1.00 | 1.2080e-01 |
| 2.00 | 1.1439e-01 |
| 3.00 | 8.5206e-02 |
| 4.00 | 6.6113e-02 |
| 5.00 | 4.7682e-02 |
| 6.00 | 3.3031e-02 |
| 7.00 | 2.2605e-02 |
| 8.00 | 5.61010e-03 |
| 9.00 | 3.6660e-03 |
| 10.00 | 8.5350e-04 |
| 11.00 | 2.7550e-04 |
| 12.00 | 4.8500e-05 |
| 13.00 | 1.6000e-06 |
| 14.00 | 0.0000e+00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set grid x y my` will enable grid lines for the major tics along both the x and y axes, and minor tics along the y axis.